# ajax data filtering not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to grab the content of the div from ajax response but it is returning the same content as the other div instead of that specific div.

```
$.ajax({
url:'test',
type:'POST',
data:{id:id},
cache:false,
success: function(data){
  $('#resp_top').html(data).find('#top');// this one works
  $('#resp_bot').html(data).find('#bottom');// this returns the same content as the above
  //$('#resp_bot').html($(data).filter('#bottom')); I have also tried this but doesn't work
}
})
```

php

```
...   
echo "<div id='top'>".$top_content."</div>";
echo "<div id='bottom'>".$bottom_content."</div>";
```

Comment: Is there any reason you are returning html instead of json? If you just want to have data available and don't need the dom structure from `test`, probably better off returning json. Not that there isn't a way to do it this way... just seems json would be a better fit for this.

Comment: Can you provide the return from the AJAX post?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're just assigning the content of the data to the divs without doing any data massaging or filtering on it.

```
$('#resp_top').html(data).find('#top')
```

Adds the data object to the HTML of the resp_top ID.

```
$('#resp_bot').html(data).find('#bottom');
```

Adds the SAME data object to the HTML of the resp_bot ID.

The find isn't doing any DOM manipulation, but rather is just finding the element and not doing anything with it.

You'd be better served by massaging the data first, then assigning it:

```
$('#resp_top').html($(data).find('#top'));
$('#resp_bot').html($(data).find('#bottom'));
```

This assumes that top/bottom are in the data object as an ID.

Comment: gives me error: syntax error, unrecognized expression

Answer (score 0):

Try using returning a JSON array with the two return values:

JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
url:'test',
type:'POST',
data:{id:id},
dataType:'json',
cache:false,
success: function(data){
  $('#resp_top').html(data[0]).find('#top');
  $('#resp_bot').html(data[1]).find('#bottom');
}
})
```

PHP:

```
echo "<div id='top'>".$top_content."</div>";
echo "<div id='bottom'>".$bottom_content."</div>";
echo json_encode(array("<div id='top'>".$top_content."</div>", "<div id='bottom'>".$bottom_content."</div>"));
```

Comment: why create the dom in the first place? and why not return something like `{ 'top': 'foo', 'bottom': 'bar' }`  so you can access with a more intuitive `data.top` and `data.bottom`

Comment: I tried this but, I am not getting any results back. console.log(data) isn't showing anything